# Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'typeof User' in angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

I got property from the json, but it shows typo error as given below: **Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'typeof User'** 
Below is my code app.component.ts:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { User, UserService } from './user.service';
@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
providers: [UserService]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
title = 'Users list';
usersdata:User;
constructor(private userService: UserService) { }
ngOnInit(){
this.userService.getUsers().then(users => this.usersdata = users.data);
}
}
```

and below is my code in user.service.ts:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
export class User {
id: number;
name: string;
data=[];
}
export class data {
name:string;
category:string;
}
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
constructor() { }
getUsers(): Promise<User> {
return Promise.resolve(
{ id: 1, name: 'Maria','data':[{
name:'ramu',category:'c' 
}]}
);
}
}
```

Below is my CODE URL [Code URL Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-type2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Below is my typo error screen-shot. Please tell me where i did a mistake?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the class `User` you defined the property `data` to be of type `any[]` by assigning an empty array `data = []`.

But in your `AppComponent` you are then trying to assign `userData` (type `User`) to `user.data` (type `any[]`), which causes the TypeScript error.

To fix the error you need use the correct types.

**Option A:** Save the whole `User` object to `userdata`

```
usersdata: User;

ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.getUsers().then(users => this.usersdata = users);
}
```

**Option B:** Fix the type of `userdata` to match the type of `User.data`.

```
usersdata: any[];

ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.getUsers().then(users => this.usersdata = users.data);
}
```

Comment: Philip,Can you please tell me how to resolve the issue

Comment: @Ramu You just need to change the type of userdata from `User` to `any[]`

Comment: @Ramu I've updated my answer, to explain how you can fix this error.

Comment: Yes i got Philip, i will check and will tell you

Answer (score 2):

Add type User like so ..

```
return Promise.resolve<User>(
{ id: 1, name: 'Maria','data':[{
name:'ramu',category:'c' 
}]}
);
```

Also in the component change type of data to `any[]`

```
usersdata:any[];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following code snippet.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { User, UserService,data } from './user.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],

}) 
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Users list';

  usersdata: Array<data>;
  constructor(private userService: UserService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.getUsers().then(users => this.usersdata = users.data);

  }
}
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-amxcsx?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts)**